# Why my app disappear at reboot?

Tags: applications, reboot

When I reboot the phone, often, some of the apps a get generic icon and won't load anymore.

A reinstall solves the problem but I'd rather not have to do that.

Device is an Acer Liquid Metal with Froyo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found out why! :D

When the phone boots - at least if I use go launcher - if the sd card is not completely mounted apps "get lost".
I've completely solved the problem activating my phone card pin code.
I turn on the phone, wait on the pin code screen without entering it for a minute and then I enter the pin: everything is perfect.
I think the problem can be also solved killing and restarting the launcher but I didn't test.

Comment: I want to confirm that the suggested answer/explanation works for me too. I've had this issue with my Acer Liquid Metal from the start, and sometimes it would be just one or two apps disappear, sometimes more. If you wait awhile before entering PIN code for SIM, all the apps are there.

Comment: Horray! I'm glad you did it too :D

Comment: you can also solve it using Tasker. See here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10497/launch-app-on-start-even-sd-card-apps/11033#11033

Comment: @Diego Doesn't that just run apps?  How does it cause the launcher to reload the app info?

Comment: Waiting does not help. It helps only to uninstall the app and reinstall it again. Installing it above the existing one, without uninstalling it first, helps until reboot. After reboot the app disappears.

Answer (score 3):

Have you moved them to or from the SD card?  My app icons disappear from my home screen when they are moved.

Comment: Yes I did...
But I'd like to find a solution for this behaviour and keep my app to the sd.
I got just a little memory on the phone side (Acer Liquid Metal)

Comment: Create the shortcut **after** moving it to the SD.  Or delete the shortcut and re-create it.

Comment: The problem is that applications in Application manager turn into gray like they're not correctly installed :/

Comment: @Pitto Oh, that's definitely a bigger problem.  Hmm.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes have this problem with my LG Optimus V. I used to re-install the app(s), now I just reboot the phone again--works 9 times out of 10 (and with those odds, the a second reboot handles that 10th time).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found it

Settings > apps > apps settings > disable all apps > apps settings > enable all apps