# Issue with the Apps that are installed on SD Card after reinserting the SD Card

Tags: external-sd, 2.1-eclair, link2sd, sony-xperia-x10-mini-pro

I am using an Xperia X10 mini pro (Android 2.1-update1). I rooted the phone and partitioned the 8GB SD Card into two parts.
1. ext3 2. FAT32.

I installed [Link2SD](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD) to move the apps to SD Card. This has been very useful as this application has an option to move the installed/updated apps to SD Card automatically.

But recently it happened to remove my SD Card from phone and inserted another 2GB SD Card for some other purpose. I started the phone and the apps that are showing on phone aren't working as I installed them on my SD card. So I put my 8 GB Micro SD card back to phone. Now the problem arose. I was not able to access the apps installed on SD Card. I had to reinstall all the apps that are there in my phone.

Is it how it behaves ? Don't I remove my SD card from phone ?

I did a little amount of Experimenting on this and found that its happening only on inserting another SD Card. My mobile is searching for the apps on the newly inserted SD Card. As there are no apps found it might be deleting the links on phone memory. This is my guess only.

Still the question stays "How to overcome this kind of scenario ?"

Comment: Did you use safely remove option (unmount) while removing SD card from your mobile?

Comment: @Power-Inside: Yes. I removed the SD Card by choosing the option Unmount SD card.

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8879/why-my-app-disappear-at-reboot/9255#9255

Comment: @Pitto: How to add PIN for the phone card?

Comment: For me (Froyo) is Android settings --> security ---> set up sim card lock

Comment: I hope that's your problem otherwise is some mess done by link2sd :(

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the phone after re-inserting the SD Card?  Some older launchers (e.g. Eclair stock) simply don't refresh their app drawer when you remount the SD Card, even though the apps are re-mounted. You can check that the apps are indeed back by going to Menu -> Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications and seeing if the "missing" apps are listed there.  If so, a reboot (or even killing the Launcher app) will fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try rebooting the phone after re-inserting the SD Card.

Some older launchers (e.g. Eclair stock) simply don't refresh their app drawer when you re-insert the SD Card, even though the apps are re-mounted. You can check that the apps are indeed back by going to `Menu -> Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications` and seeing if the "missing" apps are listed there. If so, a reboot will fix it.

Alternatively, you can simply restart the Launcher app by going to `Menu -> Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications` then scrolling down to "Launcher" and tapping on it, and then tapping on the "Force Close" button.  Now if you press the Home key, the Launcher will restart and should have all the apps back.

Comment: It didn't help me. I tried both the ways. It asked me to format the SD card. Again I had to do Partitioning and reinstalling the apps.

Comment: Sounds like the Link2SD app doesn't like you removing the card. I'd reach out to the developer for confirmation.