# Launch app on start (even SD card apps)

Tags: applications, 2.2-froyo, boot, auto-start

I'm pretty sure (despite of haven't seen them) that there are a few question about running some app when you turn on the phone. But I want a something a little more complex here. I have a few apps to run on start. Some of them have no trouble because they are installed in the phone, but the rest is installed in my SD card. As we all know (I think thats normal) after starting Android takes a few seconds to load all information saved in the SD card. How can I do to run some apps from the SD card after Android finishes loading information from the media device?

If changes something I'm using Android 2.2

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I achieve on this using [Tasker](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/). For the apps in the SD card I created a profile with the context Events -> Hardware -> Card Mounted and it loads all apps I want. For the apps in the phone I created a profile with the context Events -> System -> Device Boot and it loads all apps I want.

**Note:** The first thing you MUST do before anything in both of this contexts is wait a few seconds. In the "Card Mounted" event is to let Android load all the apps installed in the memory (I'm guessing) and in the "Device Boot" is because after booting Android is too busy doing important stuff (I'm quoting Tasker guys).